# scope of objects in cpp

Tags: c++, object, scope

can any one please explain the scope of the objects created in cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class box
{
    public:
        int i;
        box* doubled ();
};

box* box::doubled ()
{
    box *temp = new box;
    temp->i = 2*this->i;
    return temp;
}

int main ()
{
    box *obj1 = new box;
    obj1->i = 5;

    box *obj2;
    obj2 = obj1->doubled();
    delete obj1;
    cout << "i = " << obj2->i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the above sample code obj2 is a pointer holding the memory created by the function **Doubled**. The scope of the temp should be valid only to the function doubled, but it was accessible in the main function also.

So can any one explain why this was happening. I guess this is a small doubt but just not able to figure it.

Comment: And just a comment : `this->` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't delete the object dynamically created in function `doubled`, so of course the pointer to it is still valid. Operator `new` allocates the objects dynamically, and they stay in memory until explicitly destroyed. Only *the pointer pointing at the memory address* (the `temp` variable) was destroyed, but since you returned it's value (the address), the memory still belongs to a program. Actually **not deleting** it creates a memory leak.

You should use `std::unique_ptr` if you want your object to be deleted after end of a scope.

**Here's a quick example without dynamic allocation:**

```
T* foo ()
{
    T T_instance;
    return &T_instance;
}
```

It shouldn't even compile, with message similar to `returning address of local variable or temporary`, indicating, that the `T_instance` will be destroyed after program exits `foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
box *temp = new box;
```

you create a dynamically allocated `box` object that lives beyond all scopes, and a `box*` called `temp` which lives in the local scope. You have to deallocate the dynamically allocated object yourself by calling `delete` on a pointer to it, for example, like this:

```
delete temp;
```

The only thing that respects scope in the line of code above is the actual pointer `temp`, which points to that object.

```
{
   box *temp = new box; // local box* points to dynamically allocated object
}
// temp is out of scope, but the object it pointed to is still alive (and unreachable)
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `doubled` is a pointer allocated by `new`. The value of this pointer is the address of a `box` object on the heap and so although `temp` was a temporary, its value was stored in `obj2` on this line

```
obj2 = obj1->doubled();
```

and so when you access data through `obj2` it is still valid.